# Can't locate abandoned memory in iOS App

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-management

I'm developing a game for iOS and the game is being terminated after some game screens. I launched instrument in Xcode and I realized the memory keeps growing between my screens.
ARC is enabled.

I used the mark generation featured to try to track the abandoned memory between the first two screens as you can see in the image below.

Generations A is taken in TitleScreen right after firing the app.
B, C, and D are from the TitleScreen right after coming back from ChoosePlayer.

[image: instrument]

These screen have a few UIImageViews and UIButtons created via InterfaceBuilder 
I removed all programmatically created views. As you can see there seems to be a lot of abandoned memory, but I don't know how to track them since the stack comes from a intern API call.

I don't have any reference to any other view controller as well. (no strong cycle reference).

Below is the full code for the TitleScreen view controller.

I'm sure this must be a stupid error, but I can't find it. Any Ideas?
Thanks.

```
@interface SMTitleScreenViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonPlay;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonCamera;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *titleBG1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *titleBG;

- (IBAction)onButtonPlay:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)onButtonCamera:(id)sender;
@end

@implementation SMTitleScreenViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self)
    {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2509f green:0.1176f blue:0.0745f alpha:1.0f];
    UIFont* font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Jungle Roar" size:BUTTON_FONT_SIZE];

    NSString* playString = NSLocalizedString(@"Play", @"");
    NSString* cameraString = NSLocalizedString(@"Camera", @"");

    [self.buttonPlay setTitle:playString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.buttonPlay setTitle:playString forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.buttonPlay setTitleColor:color forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.buttonPlay setTitleColor:color forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    self.buttonPlay.titleLabel.font = font;

    [self.buttonCamera setTitle:cameraString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.buttonCamera setTitle:cameraString forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.buttonCamera setTitleColor:color forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.buttonCamera setTitleColor:color forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    self.buttonCamera.titleLabel.font = font;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)onButtonPlay:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"titleToChooseAnt" sender:self];
}

- (IBAction)onButtonCamera:(id)sender
{

}
@end
```

Comment: If you have ARC enabled, why are you using @autoreleasepool. Did you try it without?

Comment: Actually, I added it as a desperate measure. The original code didn't have it.

Comment: I would remove it and remove the viewDidDisappear code to start with. What are you calling abandoned memory?

Comment: Does SMTitleScreenViewController get instantiated a lot? either directly or through child classes? I ran into a similar issue and had to remove my IBOutlets and replace with tags. The reason is that each unarchived copy must create its own version when using iboutlets with xib. I'll try to see if I can lookup the documentation, but believe it was in cocoa concepts document.

Comment: It still happens without autorealease pool and viewDidDisappear. Abandoned memory is the one that's still hanging around in my app but I don't have access to it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about memory not getting released, I think the analysis will be simplified if you focus on the generations after you return to `TitleScreen`. Looking at generations when you're at `ChoosePlayer` are probably only confusing the situation.

So, fire up the app and get the initial title screen, do generation A. Go to `ChoosePlayer` (don't do a generation) and then return to `TitleScreen` again (wait a second) and do generation B. Repeat that process for generation C and D.

Having done that, focus your attention on generations C and D. Don't worry about A (which has everything consumed during startup), nor even B (which might include stuff that might be cached). You really want to focus your attention on generations after you return the second, third, and subsequent times.

Comment: Thank you Rob. I did as instructed and created generations A, B, C, D. I update the thread with the image. The results is that the memory growth and the items seem to be the sum of of the 2 generations I was capturing for each screen. I'm experiencing memory growth in each single screen in my app, I tried to profile title and choose player as they are the simpler ones. I have no clue of what's going on.

Comment: One important thing I should state is that I'm profiling this on Simulator under a Release version. (When I try to run Instruments on device it fires the app and right after quits, still don't know why)

Comment: @felipedrl OK. Thanks. BTW, you've shared your TitleScreen controller, but the problem almost certainly doesn't occur there, but rather in the code in your other view controllers that you go to and return from. You should probably iteratively comment out more and more of this subsequent code and iteratively see if you can identify what's causing this. But it's hard for us to guess on the basis of what's been provided thus far (and I agree that the Instruments extended detail is not terribly helpful).